# When going to edit a question, let us know at the START if edit queue is (close to) full

Tags: feature-request, edits

I'll sometimes try to edit the question of a new user with a very poorly worded question. Depending on the question this can take a non-insignificant amount of time. It is very frustrating to finish an edit only to find that the edit queue is full. It would be nice to know upfront, at the start of editing, if the queue is full, or within some threshold of being full before I spend time making an edit.

Comment: It does https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293373/, it currently has no way of knowing if the queue becomes full during editing.

Comment: Don't think I've ever encountered the greyed out/hover text. Does it still let you to click it and work on an edit? Because if so then I think that isn't a super obvious/intuitive warning. When I go to click on something that (in theory) I know the effect of I don't hover over it first. And a slightly different grey doesn't jump out that much.

Comment: It _probably_ doesn't still work, however it certainly only occurs when the queue is actually _full_ and not nearly full, so still a perfectly valid request

Comment: @noah The way I see it, it's live updating. So when you click the edit button and the edit queue isn't full, then it will allow you to edit the post. If after your edit the queue becomes full, then it will tell you at the end. TL;DR bad luck.

Comment: Scheduling consideration: What do you expect to happen if the edit queue becomes full *while editing*? Should you still be eligible for your review slot, i.e. should open reviews block a part of the review queue?

Comment: I wonder how many edits are being composed at any given time. Are we talking 10s, or 100s? If it's not many, would it be terrible if the system allowed edits already being composed to go through even when the queue is full? I'm in total agreement that this is one of the most annoying/ frustrating things, *especially* when the edit is non-trivial.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I could see it being scheduled a few different ways. 1) schedule on clicking edit (open reviews block queue). If necessary raise queue by 25-50 to accommodate this change. 2) schedule on clicking submit. If edit queue full then add to queue as 20X'th spot. The queue limit is used for allowing clicking edit, but if you click edit before the queue is full then you are guaranteed a spot. There would be a dynamic size queue in this solution

Comment: @zcoop98 That's a good point. What if it showed us, "23 other people are composing edits for this question. There are 75 spots left in the edit queue.", so that we have an idea of how likely our edit will be submitted. (I just spent 25 minutes editing a closed to find out that my work was for nothing. "Try again in a few moments". I kept trying and nothing changed. Grr.)

Comment: It becomes pretty irritating, when you add formatting and indentation, and then get that message. The result in the long run, will be that I just don't care about reviewing